# Is that possible to add new next and previous button for asp:Calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

The asp.Net Calendar provides Next and Previous buttons over the calendar day name but I don't like it. I am trying to add Next and Previous button outside the calendar just like the Google calendar. Then is it possible to add `MonthChangedEventArgs` to the button so I can use it just like `OnVisibleMonthChanged` provided by the asp.Net Calendar.

> FYI: When you click on the next button then the month changes. Just
>   like when you use `e.NewDate` and `e.Previous` from
>   `MonthChangedEventArgsDate` and then use `.VisibleDate` to update the
>   calendar

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304123649/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090104-1.aspx) article, I was able to use it to create a drop down box allowing you to select a month.  It is better then a button or hyperlink because I can go to December from February without that many clicks.  Here is a screen shot:

[image]

[Here is the article.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304123649/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/090104-1.aspx)

Here is a [working demo for you](https://web.archive.org/web/20171228025918/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/demos/Cal_3.aspx)

The code you are specifically after is:

```
public void Set_Calendar(object Sender, EventArgs E)
{
    cntCalendar.TodaysDate = Convert.ToDateTime(drpCalMonth.SelectedItem.Value + " 1, " + drpCalYear.SelectedItem.Value);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however, this way you have to concatenate string and validate months and years yourself before put it to .TodaysDate, is that correct?

Comment: @IDoComeBy - You are just taking in the months and years via the drop down boxes, it is much better then moving back and forth via hyperlinks (which are what those arrows are on the calendar, they render to a href links).  The links force you to go through so many different months to get to a specific month, also by default they are set so that Autopostback is true which makes your app laggy.  Your end users will thank you if you give them a drop down box, especially for months and years.

Comment: @IDoComeBy - Every month begins with 1 so you dont have to validate that, and the entries in the drop down boxes should already be validated so it doesn't make sense to validate them a second time.  You should load only valid months and years before a user selects the value.